# How to exclude lunch time from a php array of times between 2 time

Tags: php, laravel, time

Hi I am trying to get an array of dates between 2 timings and excluding the startlunch_time to endlunch_time. I have managed to display out the list of timings based on intervals, however I would like to not show the lunch time interval at all.

Below are my controller codes:

```
private function getSelectedTiming($day, $starttime, $endtime)
    {
        $timeslot = WorkingHour::where('clinic_id', $_SESSION['clinic_ID'])->where('off_day', false)->where('day', $day)->get();
        $timeslotArray = json_decode($timeslot, true);
        // $timenow = Carbon::now('Asia/Singapore')->toDateTimeString();

        foreach($timeslotArray as $timeslot){
            $start_time = strtotime($starttime);
            $end_time = strtotime($endtime);
            $startlunch = strtotime($timeslot['startlunch_time']);
            $endlunch = strtotime($timeslot['endlunch_time']);
            $duration = $timeslot['interval'];

            $array_of_time = array();
            $add_mins = $duration * 60;
            $nearest = date("h:i A", ceil(strtotime($start_time) / (60*$duration))*(60*$duration));
            $test = strtotime($nearest);
            

            while($test <= $endtime)//loop between time
            {
                if($test <= $startlunch || $test >= $endlunch){
                    $array_of_time[] = date("h:i A", $test);
                }
                $test += $add_mins;
            }

            $new_array_of_time = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($array_of_time) - 1; $i++)
            {
                $new_array_of_time[] = '' . $array_of_time[$i] . ' - ' . $array_of_time[$i + 1];
            }
            
        }
        return $new_array_of_time;

    }
```

Comment: I see that you tried to implement this in your code. What issues did you run into? Have you done any debugging? This should work in theory, so it's likely that some values aren't what you think they are.

Comment: hi @El_Vanja thanks for your input, I am able to get the array of dates however in my blade.php, I can see the lunch timing for the selected date `12:00pm - 1:00pm` where my interval for my timeslots is 30 mins. I will like to remove the `12:00pm - 1:00pm` from my view which is retrieved by my method.

Comment: I understood the problem, but as I said, you need to test your variables. Dump their values and see why your conditions don't filter out the lunch hours.

Comment: I have dd my values and these are what i got `array:20 [▼
  0 => "07:30 AM - 08:00 AM"
  1 => "08:00 AM - 08:30 AM"
  2 => "08:30 AM - 09:00 AM"
  3 => "09:00 AM - 09:30 AM"
  4 => "09:30 AM - 10:00 AM"
  5 => "10:00 AM - 10:30 AM"
  6 => "10:30 AM - 11:00 AM"
  7 => "11:00 AM - 11:30 AM"
  8 => "11:30 AM - 12:00 PM"
  9 => "12:00 PM - 01:00 PM"
  10 => "01:00 PM - 01:30 PM"
  11 => "01:30 PM - 02:00 PM"]`